# Double Click error line in LogCat doesn't work

Tags: android, error-handling, logcat

I'm writing a program for android in Eclipce.
I got a problem with error debugging, when error happens, for example *NullPointerExceptioin* and I can see that, log *the double click (on the log) is not working*? As I know it should show me the line in the code where the exception is made. 
Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.andriod.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.andriod.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at com.bignerdranch.andriod.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:57)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-27 20:28:41.202: E/AndroidRuntime(3232):     ... 11 more
```

I cant click anywhere.

Comment: I never knew that double-clicking will take you to the line, but the logcat should actually say the file name, class name, and line number in it.  Post your logcat?

Comment: 10-27 17:20:53.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andriod.test/com.andriod.test.Test}: java.lang.NullPointerException  Well maybe I'm wrong and the double click doesn't working (I was assuming that it will work..)

Comment: Is that the entire logcat?  Can't you just edit it into the original question?

Comment: There is one of the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can only double click on the line in logcat where your **package name is mentioned**.You can't double click all the lines in the LogCat

For example, For this LogCat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.sample5/com.exampl.sample5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-27 23:06:22.269: E/AndroidRuntime(348):  ... 11 more
```

Since `com.example.sample` is my package name, double clicking on the line `com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)` will show the line in code.

Comment: Has this feature been removed in the latest ADT? Nothing happens even if I double clicked on the line with my package name on it. Is there a fix?

Comment: @AniketKapse Haven't checked the latest ADT.Will update the ADT and let you know!